# How to acces to a class variable with a string?

Tags: python, string, python-import

I have the following code:

```
import Parameters

def ReadOptionFromParametersFile(self,variable_name):
  if (hasattr(Parameters, str(variable_name))):
     return Parameters.variable_name
  else:
     return 0
```

I want to call this function for different variables. In case the variable is defined on that `Parameter` file i want to read the value doing `Parameters.variable_name`. The problem is obviously that the file has no variable called `variable_name`.

I also tried:

```
Parameters.str(variable_name)
```

or

```
Parameters.eval(variable_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to access an attribute by its string name:

```
return getattr(Parameters, variable_name)
```

In fact, your entire method can be refactored to just:

```
def ReadOptionFromParametersFile(self, variable_name):
    return getattr(Parameters, variable_name, 0)
```

The third argument to `getattr` is an optional default value to return if the attribute is not found.